# Returning Count of 0 for Record summaries with 0 sub-records

Tags: count, crystal-reports, grouping

I am using crystal reports XI. I am working with a SQL database that was created before I got here, and I can't make changes to the tables or link structure. There are 4 tables in the database that I need for this report.

Table 1 - Companies || Fields: CompanyIDPK, CompanyName, YearActiveIDFK

Table 2 - ActiveYears || Fields: YearActiveIDPK, YearNameIDFK

Table 3 - YearNames || Fields: YearNameIDPK, YearName

Table 4 - CompanyOrders || Fields: OrderIDPK, CompanyIDFK, YearNameIDFK, OrderNumber, OrderCost

I want to create a report that is grouped by Year and by Company. I want each company to show the number of orders within each year, including showing 0 if there were no orders that year.

I can get the report to show all the companies that were in a given year, but as soon as I try to start showing a count, it only shows companies that had at least one order.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Are you able to create a stored procedure and base the report off that?

Comment: Show us your current report so we can help you with more detailed problem

Comment: will there be any record in order table if company has no orders?

Comment: @devlincarnate - Only if I can create it in Crystal Reports - no other programming or database software is avail to me...

Comment: @KuKeC - I don't have a report as yet. I want to make one, but every scenario I try fails.

Comment: @Siva - There is no record in order table if a company does not have orders in a given period. That is what I want to show on the report.

Comment: For this you need to outer join year so that year compulsory is retrieved and after that write  formula with isnull condition for order like if order is null for that year then display 0...try this...if unable let me know will post answer in detail

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is happening because Crystal only adds tables to your SQL query after you've added them to the designer. This happens even if you have linked your tables in the database expert.

I'm assuming you have the default join type of INNER JOIN. What's probably happening is as soon as you add your Count Summary on one of the fields in CompanyOrders, Crystal is adding it to your SQL Query.

The reason this causes a problem is because an inner join only returns records if the linked fields are in both tables. If companies haven't placed an order in the last year, they won't have any records in the CompanyOrders table. This means your SQL Query won't return any records for those companies, because those companies need to be in both tables for records to be returned.

The solution for this is to change the join type from INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN. This can be accomplished by going into the Database Expert (Menu > Database > Database Expert), clicking the Links tab, double clicking the line that goes from your Companies to your CompanyOrders table, and selecting the Left Outer Join Radio button.

Now all of the Companies will show up, but since some don't have records in the CompanyOrders table, the count for the orders will be 0.

Let me know if this was your problem.

ZMcK

Comment: I tried changing the join, but no matter how I do it, it never seems to work. I think the problem might be in how the database was structured. I seem to need to link the order table to both the company table and the year table to keep from getting all orders for the company regardless of year. However, when I do that I can't seem to change the join on the links...

Comment: Crystal won't let you change the join type after you add the table? Can you get to the Link Options pop-up menu if you double click the link's line?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say that you couldn't create database objects, so if it is possible I would create a view or stored procedure in the SQL Server database to return the data you require in the format you want and take Crystal Reports out of the equation in terms of linking tables.

Comment: Sorry, my only access to the database is through crystal reports. My access is limited to reading the records...